# how to save over a core data binary attribute

Tags: swift, core-data, attributes, save, overwrite

In my swift code my goal is to save this image to the attribute img. The problem is that instead of overwriting the previous image it just saves a new one. The saved image should always stay in slot 1 for example. Right now it saves in slot 1 then 2 then 3 etc. I just want it to stay at slot one.

```
 let gwen = UIImage(named: "l")
    
    if let imageData = gwen.self?.pngData() {
        helpImage.shareInstance.saveImage(data: imageData)
    }


class helpImage: UIViewController{

static let shareInstance = helpImage()
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext



func saveImage(data: Data) {
    let imageInstance = Pitcure(context: context)
    
    imageInstance.img = data
        
    do {
        try context.save()
        print("Image is saved")
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}}
```

Comment: You shouldn't save "big" raw data as such. It's preferred to save the data inside a File Manager, and keep in the DataBase, only a way to retrieve it (like a path, or an way to construct the path). Now, You are saving a new entity each time. There is no "replace the previous value", nor "order". Get an "id" (add an id property to the CoreData entity) to retrieve the previously saved object, and replace its desired value.

Comment: @Larme could you link me to a tutorial?